# Dynamic select field options based on selected day in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce, jquery-ui-datepicker, checkout

I have added 2 customized fields to Woocommerce checkout:

1. A jQuery-ui Datepicker field,
2. A select field (drop-down) for time.

Now, I would like that the time select field dropdown options to be depended on the chosen dates. Basically if Saturdays and Sundays are chosen, I want the time intervals to be limited (only until 15:00).

I've tried lots of different strategies, but none of them seems to be the right approach.

Here are the two customized fields:

```
//Datepicker 
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field_DP' );


function my_custom_checkout_field_DP($checkout)
{
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css", '', '', false);
wp_enqueue_style('datepicker', plugins_url('/css/datepicker.css', __FILE__), '', '', false);

/*print(' <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . plugins_url() . '/order-delivery-date-for-woocommerce/datepicker.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="' . plugins_url() . '/order-delivery-date-for-woocommerce/datepicker.js"></script>'
);
print('<script type="text/javascript" src="' . plugins_url() . '/order-delivery-date-for-woocommerce/initialize-datepicker.js"></script>');*/


echo '<script language="javascript">jQuery(document).ready
(function(){
jQuery("#e_deliverydate").width("150px");
var formats = ["MM d, yy","MM d, yy"];
jQuery("#e_deliverydate").val("").datepicker({dateFormat: formats[1], minDate:1});
jQuery("#e_deliverydate").parent().after("<div id=\'order-desc\'></div>");
});   </script>';

echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field_DP" style="width: 202%; float: left;">';

woocommerce_form_field('e_deliverydate', array(
'type' => 'text', 
'class'=> array('my-field-class form-row-first'),
'label' => __('Your Delivery Date'), 
'required' => true, 
'placeholder' => __('Pick a date')
), $checkout->get_value('e_deliverydate'));

 echo '</div>';

//Time selection field


add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field_TIME' ); 
unction my_custom_checkout_field_TIME( $checkout ) {

woocommerce_form_field( 'my_custom_field_TIME', array(
'type'          => 'select',
'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
'label'         => __('Your time'),
'required'      => true, 
'placeholder'   => __('Time to pick'),

'options'       => array(
'10:00'   => __( '10:00', 'wps' ),
'10:30'   => __( '10:30', 'wps' ),
'11:00'   => __( '11:00', 'wps' ),
'11:30'   => __( '11:30', 'wps' ),
'12:00'   => __( '12:00', 'wps' ),
'12:30'   => __( '12:30', 'wps' ),
'13:00'   => __( '13:00', 'wps' ),
'13:30'   => __( '13:30', 'wps' ),
'14:00'   => __( '14:00', 'wps' ),
'14:30'   => __( '14:30', 'wps' ),
'15:00'   => __( '15:00', 'wps' ),
'15:30'   => __( '15:30', 'wps' ),
'16:00'   => __( '16:00', 'wps' ),
'16:30'   => __( '16:30', 'wps' ),
'17:00'   => __( '17:00', 'wps' ),
'17:30'   => __( '17:30', 'wps' ),
'18:00'   => __( '18:00', 'wps' ),
)
), $checkout->get_value( 'my_custom_field_TIME' ));

echo '</div>';
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1. What is `$globalText` for? … 2. Also `$order_parent_id` is not defined… Additionally there is no order Id or parent order ID available in checkout).

Comment: Hi, I wanted to save the selected date in that variable ($globalText) and then make the time selection dropdown appear based on the selected date, but it didn't work... The line with $globalText should have been removed from the code, it's not doing anything right now :-)

Comment: I removed that line now... 
How can time field (my_custom_field_TIME) become dependent on the selected date in datepicker? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will load dynamically the time select field options through jQuery based on the selected day in jQuery-ui Datepicker field in checkout page.

I have also enabled `selectWoo` for the select field (the clone of the `select2` library).

I have merged your functions and separate scripts enqueue in a dedicated hook.

Your revisited code:

```
// Register main datepicker jQuery plugin script
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enabling_date_picker' );
function enabling_date_picker() {

    // Only on front-end and checkout page
    if( is_admin() || ! is_checkout() ) return;

    // Load the datepicker jQuery-ui plugin script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui', "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css", '', '', false);
    ## wp_enqueue_style('datepicker', plugins_url('/css/datepicker.css', __FILE__), '', '', false);
}

// Datepicker field and select time field
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'datepicker_custom_field' );
function datepicker_custom_field($checkout) {

    // $globalText = get_post_meta( $order_parent_id, 'e_deliverydate', true);

    echo '<div id="date-time-wrapper">';

    woocommerce_form_field('delivery_date', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class'=> array('delivery-date-class form-row-first'),
        'label' => __('Your Delivery Date'),
        'required' => true,
        'placeholder' => __('Pick a date')
    ), $checkout->get_value('delivery_date') );

    $options = array('' => __('Time to pick…') );

    woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_time', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array('delivery-time-class form-row-last'),
        'label'         => __('Your Delivery time'),
        'required'      => true,
        'options'       => $options,
    ),  $checkout->get_value( 'delivery_time' ) );

    // Restricted options array
    $options1 = array(
        '10:00'   => __( '10:00', 'wps' ),
        '10:30'   => __( '10:30', 'wps' ),
        '11:00'   => __( '11:00', 'wps' ),
        '11:30'   => __( '11:30', 'wps' ),
        '12:00'   => __( '12:00', 'wps' ),
        '12:30'   => __( '12:30', 'wps' ),
        '13:00'   => __( '13:00', 'wps' ),
        '13:30'   => __( '13:30', 'wps' ),
        '14:00'   => __( '14:00', 'wps' ),
        '14:30'   => __( '14:30', 'wps' ),
        '15:00'   => __( '15:00', 'wps' ),
    );

    // The other part of options array
    $options2 = array(
        '15:30'   => __( '15:30', 'wps' ),
        '16:00'   => __( '16:00', 'wps' ),
        '16:30'   => __( '16:30', 'wps' ),
        '17:00'   => __( '17:00', 'wps' ),
        '17:30'   => __( '17:30', 'wps' ),
        '18:00'   => __( '18:00', 'wps' ),
    );

    // Merging options arrays 
    $options1 = array_merge($options, $options1); // Partial
    $options  = array_merge($options1,$options2); // Full

    echo '<br clear="all"></div>';

    ?>
    <script language="javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        var a = <?php echo json_encode($options); ?>,
            b = <?php echo json_encode($options1); ?>,
            c = new Date(),
            s = 'select#delivery_time';

        // Utility function to fill dynamically the select field options
        function dynamicSelectOptions( opt ){
            var o = '';
            $.each( opt, function( key, value ){
                o += '<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>';
            });
            $(s).html(o);
        }

        // Once DOM is loaded
        if( c.getDay() == 6 || c.getDay() == 0 )
            dynamicSelectOptions( b );
        else
            dynamicSelectOptions( a );

        // Select time to selectWoo
        $(s).selectWoo();

        // Datepicker
        $('#delivery_date').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'MM d, yy',
            minDate:1,
            onSelect: function(){
                // Live event: On selected date event
                var d = new Date($(this).val());
                if( d.getDay() == 6 || d.getDay() == 0 )
                    dynamicSelectOptions( b );
                else
                    dynamicSelectOptions( a );
            }
        }).parent().after('<div id="order-desc"></div>');
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot! 

There is just a small issue. When I choose Saturday or Sunday in April, the time select field works fine, but for same selections in July and June, time select field shows until 18:00 ($option2) and again works correct for September... Can't see where the problem comes from. The getDay() function is the same for every month, isn't it? 

And is the dateFormat: 'MM d, yy' correct? Shouldn't there be an extra "d"? Thanks.

Comment: sorry for not accepting. This is my first post here, so I'm new to stackoverflow. Have accepted your answer now..

Comment: I can see you don't have this problem in your server. Maybe some of my other code is causing this. Any ideas where I should look?

Comment: I suspected that the localize function for Datepicker could cause this problem, and tried to disable that function, but the problem still remains. Any suggestions?

Comment: @s_83 So sorry, as it is really not possible for me to know what is going on in your installation that makes the issue you describe. I haven't be able to reproduce that problem. You should try to disable your other customizations, plugins (making a backup before) and re enable them one by one to find the guilty… If you can't find anything, may be you can ask a new question adding my code to your question and try to explain clearly your issue…

Comment: I have tried to disable all other custom code and plugins, but problem still there. It's actually only for May and October that time select field shows the whole range no matter which day is chosen... Very strange. I'll make a new post later on this. Thanks for your help anyways.